# Spring Boot: Custom exception adds prefix to the exception message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

In a Spring Boot app, I created a custom `GlobalExceptionHandler` and add the following method to handle `ConstraintViolationException` for invalid file type during upload process:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolationException(
                              ConstraintViolationException ex, 
                              WebRequest request) {
    log.error("Invalid file type.", ex);
    return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, request);
}
```

My `buildErrorResponse` works correctly and build proper responses for other handle methods. However, It adds "*uploadFile.file:*" prefix to my error message.

My questions:

1. Is there any problem with my `handleConstraintViolationException` implementation? If not, how can I fix that problem?
2. I think there is no need to create custom exception class as shown below for the exceptions that is already defined in `javax.validation` like `ConstraintViolationException`. Is that true?

**Note:** If you need to have a look at my `GlobalExceptionHandler`, it is something like on [this GitHub](https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/blob/master/spring-boot/exception-handling/src/main/java/io/reflectoring/exception/exception/GlobalExceptionHandler.java).

Comment: It seems to be related to `@Validated` annotation used on the Controller. However, I also tried to use it like `public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@Validated @ValidFile @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {...}`, but this time not validating. Any idea?

Comment: @cif here is minimal example that I followed: https://gist.github.com/susimsek/03b6a4d695b864dfe95d1b31959b3e53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer For Question 1: Your implementation not wrong but have some missing properties. For best practice to my opinion you can create a class to use it for error response which can contains like statusCode,timestamp,message,description.
You can use method like this in your handleConstraintViolationException method:

```
private ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>generateErrorMessage(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request){
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage.ErrorMessageBuilder()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
            .timeStamp(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now()))
            .message(ex.getMessage())
            .description(request.getDescription(false))
            .build();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually I had already implemented all of them. But I think the problem is related to my builder method.